# Get Information about hyperledger Fabric

Tags: java, sdk, hyperledger-fabric, peer

I am working on Hyperledger Fabric using SDK 1.4

I am trying to get a list of all existing peers and orders in hyperledger without being related to a channel. I found only `this` way to get peers which brings only peers related to a channel: `this.channel.getPeers()`

In addition, I want to get other information such as:

- a list of blocks contained in a given channel
- Getting a block by Id or by Hash

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think can you query the information from the system chaincode QSCC. It provides ledger query APIs such as getting blocks and transactions, including:
 - GetChainInfo returns BlockchainInfo
 - GetBlockByNumber returns a block
 - GetBlockByHash returns a block
 - GetTransactionByID returns a transaction

You can refer to more information here.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/chaincode4noah.html
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5841

Comment: Thank you for responding , i already used the QSCC methods :  GetChainInfo ( returns null ) , GetBlockByNumber  ( returns a static string "GetBlockByNumber" ) so i decided maybe to try to get the organisation lists in order to get the peers corresponding to that org ... i don't know until now howa to do that so if you have an idea please it's so urgent .. and thanks :) :)